# How to automatically select a non-consecutive range of rows/columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, selection

I have an Excel document in which I want to select a few hundred rows (not necessarily consecutive), in order to then copy them into another document (which will incidentally serve as a source document for a Word address label document).

I have everything figured out regarding how to do this, except for the first part: selecting the appropriate rows.

Is there some dialog somewhere in which I can input a string such as "1-5, 7, 9-13, 24-28, 33", whereupon the indicated rows are selected? Or do I have to use some kind of macro?

EDIT: Note that what I'm after is a regular selection. I want to "automate" the arduous process of CTRL-clicking column after column in order to achieve the desired selection.

Comment: Is this a recurring or one time task? What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Do you mean, some times you want to copy columns only, and some times only rows only and not a combination or rows and columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you, assuming that (in the code below) A1 is where you'll put the data.

Please note, it will accept numbers as rows, strings as columns

```
Option Explicit
Sub HighlightAllSortsOfMadness()

Dim values() As String

values = Split(Range("A1").Value, ",") 'A1 is rows and columns you specify, such as 1,4,6,7,B,D . Separate each with a comma, 


Dim result As String

Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To UBound(values)
        If values(i) = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If

    result = result & values(i) & ":" & values(i) & ","

    Next i

    Range(Left(result, Len(result) - 1)).Select

End Sub
```

Before

[image]

And after I run the macro

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you know the letters/numbers, you can select them with a simple formula: =B:B;D:D;G:G;I:I;K:K;N:P;

B:B will select entire column.
N:P will select entire columns form N to P, included.

Comment: This looks a bit like what I want to do. But where am I to input this formula, and how do I copy the contents of the indicated columns so that I can paste it into another document?

Note that what I'm after is a regular selection, not a cell reference. I want to "automate" the arduous process of CTRL-clicking column after column in order to achieve the desired selection.

Comment: Manually, in the new sheet (or workbook), select A1 and input the formula =[Contacts.xlsx]Sheet1!A:A. For doing it automatically, you'll need a macro/vba script, I'm sure you'll be able to do it with a little how to: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=58648